# Stripe Checkout not working on phone browers, desktop browers fine

Tags: android, iphone, meteor, stripe-payments

I've got stripe working fine on my webpage but once I go on the webpage with my Android phone browser and try to checkout it gives me an error saying "The payment couldn't be completed because the original page seems to no longer be open. Close your tabs and try again.." I think it has something to do with the fact that on phone browsers the stripe Checkout form opens up in a new tab whereas on desktops it opens in a modal...

anyone ever experience this?

Comment: I'm glad you solved your problem. Another one related to "Stripe Checkout not working on phone browers, desktop browers fine" is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36044921/stripe-checkout-doesnt-send-request-to-server-on-mobile

Comment: I finally added my related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38979848/stripe-checkout-works-on-desktop-browsers-but-doesnt-send-request-to-stripe-ser

Answer (score 0):

There was a similar problem with regards to the OAuth flow on mobile devices:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/8B1kjjvRimE

It seems to be a limitation with how mobile browsers are implemented so there's not much that can be done on that side.  I think the best (only?) option is to integrate your checkout form into the page instead of in a popup.  Not sure if Stripe offers this functionality but they probably do and if not, I'm sure there are other payment processors that do.

Answer (score 0):

I emailed them and got it fixed. The thing to look out for is importing a download of checkout on your own server rather than just using the link they provide. For example, use:

```
<script
src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
data-key="YOUR_KEY"
data-amount="2000"
data-name="Pay"
data-description="Pay $20.00"
data-image="myimg.png">
</script>
```

instead of something like:

```
<script
src="/files/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
data-key="YOUR_KEY"
data-amount="2000"
data-name="Pay"
data-description="Pay $20.00"
data-image="myimg.png">
</script>
```

Not entirely sure what I may have done in my server file to cause the error, but this change fixed it, so hopefully that helps!

Comment: hmm this is odd that it worked for you (didn't work for me). I would also not want to do this in case there are modifications stripe makes to their API. I emailed them about this same issue and have not heard back on the right approach. Seems building my own custom checkout is going to be the resolution :(

Comment: @Hans I wonder if you have any ideas about why Stripe Checkout would suddenly stop working from mobile browsers and continue working from desktop: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38979848/stripe-checkout-works-on-desktop-browsers-but-doesnt-send-request-to-stripe-ser