# stripe checkout doesn't send request to server on mobile

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm using `stripe checkout`.

On `desktop`, after adding credit card info and submitting, the request with the payment token is sent to our server for processing.

However on `mobile`, specifically a `nexus 5`, after submitting, it redirects to the previous page it was on before submitting and no request was sent to our server.

One difference is that on `desktop` the `checkout` is a popup whereas on `mobile` its a page redirect to a `stripe mobile checkout page`

Comment: Would you mind writing to Stripe's support to report this issue? Using the form https://support.stripe.com/email or simply support@stripe.com. Please include as many details as you can, such as Android version and which browser and version were used.

Comment: @Ywain I'm having the same problem. Leland at Stripe might be trying to look into this for me; I'll send him this link. Do you know what the solution ended up being?  This has been killing me for days! I haven't been able to get any other work done.

Comment: @Mlennie I'd be so grateful if you'd tell me how you solved this problem. I've been really struggling for days.

Comment: @Ryan I think this was an issue with stripe. I think I sent them an email and I think they fixed it. So I would recommend contacting stripe support if you're having a similar problem.

Comment: @Mlennie thank you so much for your response!  Stripe support hasn't been able to help me, unfortunately. If I figure it out, I'll post to StackOverflow.

Comment: I added my own question with details and will post updates to it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38979848/stripe-checkout-works-on-desktop-browsers-but-doesnt-send-request-to-stripe-ser